# Как сделать определенные строки одним цветом?

Tags: c#, winforms

Доброе утро,  мне нужно, что бы строки определенве с надписями "перемещен" выделялись зеленым цветом , а остальные красным в listbox.
Вот мой метод покраски шрифта

```
 Private void DrawItem(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)
 {
      Brush mybrush = Brushes.Green;
      Brush mybrush2 = Brushes.Red;

      e.Graphics.DrawString(listbox1.items[e.Index].ToString(),e.Font, mybrush , e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
 }
```

В данный момент перекрашивается все в зеленый, а нужно, что бы только определенные строки окрашивались. Как это можно сделать? И да, использую WinFoms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ставьте у ListBox свойство DrawMode равное OwnerDrawFixed и код, что-то вроде

```
    private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        string text = ((ListBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString();
        Color color = Color.White;
        if (text == "перемещен")
            color = Color.Green;
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(color), e.Bounds);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(text,
                e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
```

вешайте на дравИтем

[image: Получилось так]

Comment: ну и соответственно Color.Red, если надо. Просто глаза резало, поставил белый.

Comment: Еще такой вопрос, а если в строке такого типа запись "файл.тхт перемещен" что бы именно эта строка с содержанием слова "перемещен" окрасить?

Comment: Все решил проблему сам.

Answer (score 1):

Если не ошибаюсь, то нужно выставить у `ListBox` свойство `DrawMode`([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawmode.aspx)) равное `OwnerDrawVariable`. Затем создать обработчик события `DrawItem` и в этом обработчике разрисовывать:

```
private void lstBox_DrawItem(object sender,   
          System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)  
    {  
        // Перерисовываем фон всех элементов ListBox.  
        e.DrawBackground();  

        // Создаем объект Brush.  
        Brush myBrush = Brushes.Black;  

        // Определяем номер текущего элемента  
        switch (e.Index)  
        {  
            case 0:  
                myBrush = Brushes.Red;  
                break;  
            case 1:  
                myBrush = Brushes.Green;  
                break;  
            case 2:  
                myBrush = Brushes.Blue;  
                break;  
            default: myBrush = Brushes.Yellow;  
                break;  
        }  

        //Если необходимо, закрашиваем фон   
        //активного элемента в новый цвет  
        //e.Graphics.FillRectangle(myBrush, e.Bounds);  

        // Перерисовываем текст текущего элемента  
        e.Graphics.DrawString(  
            ((ListBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString(),   
            e.Font, myBrush, e.Bounds,   
            StringFormat.GenericDefault);  

        // Если ListBox в фокусе, рисуем прямоугольник   
        //вокруг активного элемента.  
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();  
    }
```

Comment: Это все я делал и все окрашивает... Проблема в том, что нужно, что бы определенные строки окрашивало, т.е. те строки в которых присутствует слово "перемещен".

Comment: Так в коде смотрите `switch` и замените там выбор из 1,2,3 на проверку условия есть в строке слово "перемещен" или нет.